# C# combobox appropriate event type

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox and with this I have a associated event

```
private void comboBox8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

My comobox is populated with two items `a and b`

I am setting `combobox8.selectedItem = x` where `x= a or b`. My event only fires if I select `a` from `b` or `b` from `a`. **It does not fire** if I again select `a` from `a`.

How can I do it and what's the appropriate event to deal with it ?

Moreover I am doing it all programmatically.

Comment: perhaps you want to move the code to the `.Click` Event instead.. try moving the code there or the `SelectedValueChanged`

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to do in this event. The value did not change - that's why it was not fired - it feels like you're just trying to do something in the wrong place.

Comment: If you go from `a` to `a`, the selected index hasn't changed, so `SelectedIndex` *`Changed`* won't fire.

Comment: Actually i am refreshing the form and if the value of comboBox is same I execute the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that the event doesn't fire again. The selected item doesn't change. Depending on what you actually want, there are [a lot of events you can utilize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events.aspx). You might start with [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx), or [DropDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown.aspx), or [DropDownClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownclosed.aspx), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because its selected index changed event. From a to a nothing has been changed. You can try onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

It won't fire because Selected Index did not change...

Take a look at msdn documentation for a list of comboBox events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events.aspx

You'll find out you can use more one depending on what you want to achieve (`leave`,`lostfocus`, [...])

Answer (score 0):

Because the index did not change, the event is not fired. Since you need this processing when you are refreshing the form programmatically, call the appropriate code programmatically as well:

```
private void comboBox8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessComboBoxInput();
}

private void RefreshFormProgrammatically()
{
    // Refresh the form here...
    ProcessComboBoxInput();
}

private void ProcessComboBoxInput()
{
     // Process the comboBox8 here...
}
```